# Import method in folder with reserved word

Tags: python, import, python-importlib

I have the following file structure:

```
root
|
folder1 -> lambda -> lambda.py -> myMethod()
|
test-> lambda_test -> test_lambda.py
```

I would like to `import lambda.myMethod()` into my `test.lambda.py` file for testing but python *understandably* complains about `lambda` being a keyword.

I tried various combos with `importlib` without much luck.

Comment: The only answer is to change the name of your file.  You can't have a module with the same name as a reserved word.  That's just a rule.

Comment: @TimRoberts yeah that seems to be the case, and I will be renaming it (it's just a new gig and my first week) I was a bit intrigued to see how you can overcome that naming with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your directory structure:

```
folder1/lambda/__init__.py
               lambda.py
test/lambda_test/test_lambda.py
```

And the contents of each file:

```py
# folder1/lambda/__init__.py
import importlib
lambda_module = importlib.import_module('lambda.lambda')
```

```py
# folder1/lambda/lambda.py
def hello_world():
    print("hello world")
```

```py
# test/lambda_test/test_lambda.py
import importlib
import sys

sys.path.append("../../folder1")
my_lambda_import = importlib.import_module("lambda")

my_lambda_import.lambda_module.hello_world()
```

Comment: Tried this method it didn't work as it didn't find the module. I think the relative path matters here as I'm importing in the test file.

Comment: Updated to deal with relative paths